# Endorsed directory is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In eclipse I receive this error:  "Endorsed directory ... is missing.  You may need to perform a Maven command line build to create it."

It seems to be related to this plugin in my pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The project builds successfully on the command line.  I did a clean build in Eclipse but still have this error.

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Doing a clean in eclipse won't necessarily do a full maven build.  Try doing a run as->maven install on your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with
`<endorseddirs>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorseddirs>`

Refer to Link - [Pass Compiler Arguments](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html)

Comment: `<compilerArguments>` is deprecated in `maven-compiler-plugin`:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArguments